# Wrong color on :hover for a navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to make a navbar in React and I have a problem with the hover, after the click the current element is underline and I want this line to be the same color as the element. Right now the color of the underline is always the same as the last element (here LOGIN) i don't understand why

Here is what I did (I tried so much different ways it is the best I've found) :

```js
const Navigation = () => {

    const handleMouseClick = (color) => {
        console.log(document.documentElement.style);
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--colorUnderline', color);
    };


    const NavItem = (props) => {
        return <li
            style={{ color: props.color }}
            onClick={handleMouseClick(props.color)}
        >{props.title}</li >;
    };

    return (
        <div className="navigation">
            <ul>
                <NavLink to="/artists" className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}>
                    <NavItem color={variables.artistsColor} title="ARTISTS" />
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/project" className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}>
                    <NavItem color={variables.projectColor} title="PROJECT" />
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/login" className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}>
                    <NavItem color={variables.loginColor} title="LOGIN" />
                </NavLink>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Here the scss:

```css
:root {
  --colorUnderline: #61dafb;
}
.navigation {
  font-family: "font-1";

  ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 40px;

    li {
      padding: 50px;
      display: grid;
      transition: 0.2s;
      cursor: pointer;

      &:hover {
        opacity: .5;
      }
    }

    .nav-active {
      position: relative;

      &::after {
        
        content: "";
        height: 4px;
        width: 0;
        background: var(--colorUnderline);
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 10px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-animation: anim 0.3s ease forwards;
        animation: anim 0.6s ease forwards;

        @-webkit-keyframes anim {
          to {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }

        @keyframes anim {
          to {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my colors are in my setting.scss like this :

```css
$artistsColor: #FFBE0B;
$projectColor: #65B8C4;
$loginColor: #9D63C6;
:export {
  artistsColor: $artistsColor;
  projectColor: $projectColor;
  loginColor: $loginColor;
}
```

For sure there is a simpler way to do that.

Comment: This would be  much easier to diagnose with rendered HTML and CSS. Please put them in a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: I dont know how to use NavLink in a snippet demo

Comment: You can't, which is why I said _rendered_ HTML. That's what shows up in your browser.